# Tests failed, error Unexpected token, expected "{"

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jestjs

I'm a bit new to angular, recently I had to upgrade my angular to version 15. My application functions fine, but the tests no longer work. The test suite files are found, I'm using files with extension .spec.ts. Can anyone help me to get my tests running again? When I run ng test I get the following errors for each test suite file:

```
Test suite failed to run

SyntaxError: angular-app-1\node_modules\@angular\core\testing\index.d.ts: Unexpected token, expected "{" (33:7)

  31 |  * @codeGenApi
  32 |  */
> 33 | export declare const __core_private_testing_placeholder__ = "";
     |        ^
  34 |
  35 | /**
  36 |  * @deprecated use `waitForAsync()`, (expected removal in v12)

> 1 | import "jest-preset-angular/setup-jest";
    | ^
  2 |

 at instantiate (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parse-error/credentials.ts:62:21)
  at toParseError (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parse-error.ts:60:12)
  at Parser.raise (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/tokenizer/index.ts:1490:19)
  at Parser.unexpected (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/tokenizer/index.ts:1531:16)
  at Parser.parseExport (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:2389:10)
  at Parser.parseStatementContent (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:580:25)
  at Parser.parseStatementLike (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:417:17)
  at Parser.parseModuleItem (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:354:17)
  at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1359:16)
  at Parser.parseBlockBody (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1333:10)
  at Parser.parseProgram (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:226:10)
  at Parser.parseTopLevel (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:208:25)
  at Parser.parse (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/index.ts:45:10)
  at parse (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/index.ts:67:38)
  at parser (../../node_modules/@babel/core/src/parser/index.ts:28:19)
      at parser.next (<anonymous>)
  at normalizeFile (../../node_modules/@babel/core/src/transformation/normalize-file.ts:51:24)
      at normalizeFile.next (<anonymous>)
  at run (../../node_modules/@babel/core/src/transformation/index.ts:38:36)
      at run.next (<anonymous>)
  at transform (../../node_modules/@babel/core/src/transform.ts:29:20)
      at transform.next (<anonymous>)
  at evaluateSync (../../node_modules/gensync/index.js:251:28)
  at fn (../../node_modules/gensync/index.js:89:14)
  at stopHiding - secret - don't use this - v1 (../../node_modules/@babel/core/src/errors/rewrite-stack-trace.ts:97:14)
  at transformSync (../../node_modules/@babel/core/src/transform.ts:66:52)
  at ScriptTransformer._instrumentFile (../../node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:379:46)
  at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (../../node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:519:33)
  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (../../node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:569:40)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (../../node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:607:25)
  at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/jest-preset-angular/setup-jest.js:1:107)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/test-setup.ts:1:1)
```

This is my jest.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
testMatch: ["**/+(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|js)?(x)"],
transform: {
    "^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$": "ts-jest"
},
resolver: "@nrwl/jest/plugins/resolver",
moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "js", "html"],
collectCoverage: true,
coverageReporters: ["html"]
```

};